# floated divs are overlapping and the inner content is wrapping. How can I make more responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the following to be more responsive.  It seems the two divs are wrapping over each other and only the buttons are flowing w/ the content.  How would I go about getting the two divs to be more responsive?

Here is a full page example:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/eaerpuhb

Here is the code:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/eaerpuhb

```
<html> 

 <head> 
 <title> test </title>
 <style>
    .settings {
        max-width: 970px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 3px;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .setting {
        margin: 5px 0;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .name { width: 200px; }
    .save {
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .saveAsNew, .cancel { margin-left: 4px; }
    .topRightLinks {
        display: block;
        float: right;       
    }
    .dashboardSettings {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .divSections {
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-left: auto;
        text-align: right;
    }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div class='topRightLinks'>
      <div class='dashboardSettings'>
        <span class='addSection'>Add Report</span>
        <div class='divSections'>
          <span>Choose a report:</span>
          <select class='ddlAddSection'><option value='1'>Account Analytics</option></select>
          <input type='button' value='Add'/>
          <input type='button' value='Close'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='settings'>
        <div class='setting'>Dashboard Name: 
            <input type='text' maxlength='64' class='name' />
            <div class='save'>
                <input class='save' type='button' value='Save' />
                <input class='saveAsNew' type='button' value='Save As New' />
                <input class='cancel' type='button' value='Cancel' />
            </div>
    </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here try this. i guess this is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .settings {
   width: 59%;
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   padding: 3px;
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
   text-align: left;
  }
  .setting {
   margin: 5px 0;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
  }
  .name {
   width: 200px;
  }
  .save {
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
  }
  .saveAsNew,
  .cancel {
   margin-left: 4px;
  }
  .topRightLinks {
   display: block;
   width: 39%;
   float: right;
  }
  .dashboardSettings {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   text-align: right;
  }
  .divSections {
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin-left: auto;
   text-align: right;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: block;
  }
```

```html
 <div class='topRightLinks clearfix'>
  <div class='dashboardSettings'>
   <span class='addSection'>Add Report</span>
   <div class='divSections'>
    <span>Choose a report:</span>
    <select class='ddlAddSection'>
     <option value='1'>Account Analytics</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' value='Add' />
    <input type='button' value='Close' />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class='settings clearfix'>
  <div class='setting clearfix'>Dashboard Name:
   <input type='text' maxlength='64' class='name' />
   <div class='save'>
    <input class='save' type='button' value='Save' />
    <input class='saveAsNew' type='button' value='Save As New' />
    <input class='cancel' type='button' value='Cancel' />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```